# Reverting to default react select props based on a condition in React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a away to reset to a default prop value in React Select?
I want to render things in a specific way only based on a condition.

See the code below:

```
MultiValueLabel: this.props.valueWithImage ? nullComponent : paddedComponent(this.props.valueRenderer),
MultiValueRemove: this.props.valueWithImage ? this.MultiValueRemove : nullComponent,
```

I do not want to write the whole ReactSelect tag separately in a conditional as most of the props I am giving it are similar in both those conditions.

Note that null, nullComponent, undefined, etc don't work there. Because I don't want it null, rather I want it to take its original value (whatever reactSelect is giving it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution, we can just do:

```
MultiValueLabel: this.props.valueWithImage ? components.MultiValueLabel : paddedComponent(this.props.valueRenderer),
MultiValueRemove: this.props.valueWithImage ? this.MultiValueRemove : components.MultiValueRemove,
```